# How can you tell if an exe depends on certain Qt image format dlls or not?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, required

qgif4.dll, qjpeg4.dll, qtiff4.dll all implement these functions:

```
qt_plugin_instance
qt_plugin_query_verification_data
```

`dumpbin` possibly isnt smart enough to see if any functions in qgif4.dll, qjpeg4.dll, qtiff4.dll *could* be called and thus are needed by the application.
To be precise: I ran `dumpbin` and it said our exe doesn't depend on any of the above dlls's, but my manager still has doubts whether or not the qjpg4.dll is needed. Is there a way to tell for sure before shipping?

Of course we need to supply all dlls needed by our app. But we want to supply what is *essential* only, since the app has to run on a stripped down embedded version of Windows XP with size constraints: all is run from virtal RAM disk.

Comment: In Windows, I personally use http://www.dependencywalker.com/. It scans a binary's dependencies recursively. This lets you see exactly what you need. Note that this doesn't work for libraries you load at run time manually, for example if you use the WINAPI function LoadLibrary.

Comment: The dependency walker is useless for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are Qt plugins. They are loaded on the fly by Qt depending on which image formats you use in your Qt code.

You should be able to  deduce which ones are needed by looking at which image formats you load with Qt code.

You can also run your program while Process Monitor is running. It will trace, among others, all loaded DLLs, so you will know that those loaded DLLs are needed (needed for the code you ran during that session. This method does not guarantee that some other code of the program that you did not execute in that session does not depend on an other image plugin)